Why when running airflow to the simplest DAG it seems to be run twice?
I am starting to learn how to use Airflow for pipelines.
I have the simplest DAG in

from __future__ import annotations

import textwrap
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="simplest_tutorial",
    # [START default_args]
    # These args will get passed on to each operator
    # You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
    default_args={
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email": ["airflow@example.com"],
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    description="An even simpler tutorial DAG",
    schedule=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="print_date",
        bash_command="date",
    )

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="sleep",
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command="sleep 5",
        retries=3,
    )

t1 >> t2


When I run this DAG I get this in Airflow
Airflow DAG screen
so it seems the DAG has been ran twice!.
Also if I click on the green bars to the left I can see that
one run was not externally triggered and the other one was.
The audit log is also difficult to understand
Audit log
Why is this DAG being run twice?

Did you trigger a manual run from the airflow ui or the cli?

I use the UI. I have not used the CLI but I suppose it is my next learn item

The one run is actually getting triggered as you have used the schedule=timedelta(days=1) parameter. As soon as you unpause the DAG, it will trigger a DAG run as it will satisfy the trigger condition mentioned in the schedule parameter.
Have a look over this documentation to understand how scheduling works in Airflow - Schedule DAGs in Airflow
If you don't want the DAG to trigger any run automatically, you can always provide schedule=None in the parameters to disable scheduling.
